# Warning when importing contacts/activities

Tags: contacts, activities, import

warning pop up note when importing contacts or activities, same warning on the drupal demo site, go to contacts -> import contacts/activities: 'Upload max filesize ('upload_max_filesize') should not exceed Post max size ('post_max_size') as defined in PHP.ini, please check with your system administrator'.

Is this something to worry about or this warning has always been there?

Answer (score 4):

This message means that your upload will likely fail on larger files. Update your PHP.ini file to fix this conflict.

More info: [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/263967)